# AirFlow Python operator error: got an unexpected keyword argument 'conf'

Tags: python, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to trigger dbt cloud via AirFlow and unable to find an answer to the error below

> ERROR - run_job() got an unexpected keyword argument 'conf'

I am using the plugin code from https://github.com/sungchun12/airflow-dbt-cloud

```
"""Main handler method to run the dbt Cloud job and track the job run status"""
        job_run_id = self._trigger_job()
        print(f"job_run_id = {job_run_id}")

        visit_url = f"https://cloud.getdbt.com/#/accounts/{self.account_id}/projects/{self.project_id}/runs/{job_run_id}/"
        print(f"Check the dbt Cloud job status! Visit URL:{visit_url}")

        while True:
            time.sleep(1)  # make an api call every 1 second

            job_run_status = self._get_job_run_status(job_run_id)

            print(f"job_run_status = {job_run_status}")

            if job_run_status == dbt_job_run_status.SUCCESS:
                print(f"Success! Visit URL: {visit_url}")
                break
            elif (
                    job_run_status == dbt_job_run_status.ERROR
                    or job_run_status == dbt_job_run_status.CANCELLED
            ):
                raise Exception(f"Failure! Visit URL: {visit_url}")
```

I am calling the function via the following code

```
   run_dbt_cloud_job = PythonOperator(
            task_id="run_dbt_cloud_job",
            python_callable=dbt_cloud_job_runner_config.run_job,
            provide_context=True,
        )
```

And get the error

> run_job() got an unexpected keyword argument 'conf'

I'm not sure why it is not working.

If I change the provide context = False then I get following error

> ERROR - 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: What does the `dbt_cloud_job_runner_config` look like?

Comment: class dbt_cloud_job_runner(dbt_cloud_job_vars, dbt_job_run_status):
    """Utility to run dbt Cloud jobs.

    Inherits dbt_cloud_job_vars(dataclass) and dbt_job_run_status(dataclass)

    Parameters
    ----------
        account_id(int): dbt Cloud account id
        project_id(int): dbt Cloud project id
        job_id(int): dbt Cloud job id
        cause(str): dbt Cloud cause(ex: name of DAG)
        dbt_cloud_api_key(str)(OPTIONAL): dbt Cloud api key to authorize programmatically interacting with dbt Cloud
    """

Comment: See the class  here https://github.com/sungchun12/airflow-dbt-cloud/blob/main/dags/dbt_cloud_utils.py

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you need to pass `**kwargs`  on the parameters.

You can see this example:

```
def my_mult_function(number, **kwargs): 
return number*number
```

It is because if you set `provide_context=True`, the `PythonOperator` will export context to make available for callables to use. A generic variable will catch all the keywords arguments.

You can see the [PythonOperator class](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/operators/python_operator.py#L108).

If your code returns  `this error “'NoneType' object is not subscriptable”`, it is because there are no results in your query. A solution to this is to change the query to use scalar().

You can see this example.

```
    triggered_by = (
    session.query(Log.owner)
    .filter(Log.dag_id == "killer_dag")
    .limit(1)
    .scalar()
)
```

You can see more documentation in this [link](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_modules/airflow/models/dag.html).

Comment: Hi Raul       The function does not except any argument                                                
         def run_job(self) -> None:
        """Main handler method to run the dbt Cloud job and track the job run status"""
        job_run_id = self._trigger_job()
        print(f"job_run_id = {job_run_id}")         .

Comment: Now I am getting the error  If I include kwargs I get the error  [2022-02-07 18:55:43,946] {taskinstance.py:1152}                                                                                                  
         ERROR - 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @recyclinguy I updated my answer.

Comment: Hi Raul - I am bit lost. I am using  class base operator provided in the link .I am calling method run job which does not accept any argument and is part of class dbt_cloud_job_vars:  

        # Single task to execute dbt Cloud job and track status over time
        run_dbt_cloud_job = PythonOperator(
            task_id="run_dbt_cloud_job",
            python_callable=dbt_cloud_job_runner_config.run_job,
            provide_context=True,
        )

Comment: @recyclinguy In line 14 in the file [dbt_cloud_example.py](https://github.com/sungchun12/airflow-dbt-cloud/blob/main/dags/dbt_cloud_example.py), you can find the dbt_cloud_job_runner where you set the parameters of your project (account_id, project_id, job_id,cause).

Comment: Hi Raul - Yes I am passing the parameters already                                    
      dag_file_name = __file_                                               
        _dbt_cloud_job_runner_config = dbt_cloud_job_runner(
    account_id=12345, project_id=12345, job_id=12345,cause=dag_file_name
)                                                                                                                                   
    and in python callable python_callable=dbt_cloud_job_runner_config.run_job, provide_context=True,